# Reloading BotDetect Captcha using javascript

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, captcha, botdetect

is there anyway for refreshing BotDetect captcha by javascript? 
something like what refresh button on captcha module does!

[image: refresh button on BotDetect captcha]

i tried to find and trigger the refresh link by using following code:

```js
var reloadLink = $("#ExampleCaptcha_ReloadIcon");
            reloadLink.trigger('click');
```

but it didnt work.
im using ASP.NET MVC 5

Answer (score 1):

Try using

$('.BDC_ReloadIcon').trigger('click');

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`const captcha = $('#botdetect-captcha').captcha({
 captchaEndpoint: 'simple-captcha-endpoint.ashx'
 });`

And where you need - 
`captcha.reloadImage();`